# GLUT mouse clicks detection

Tags: glut

I designed a picture and set it as a background for a window. What I want is that the bits of the picture act as buttons, for example if I use the screenshot of the desktop as a background image for my window, I would like to make the Start button act like a button, would I have to draw an area that defines the perimeter where the clicks of the mouse have a particular action?

Answer (score 1):

Well, glut is just for drawing, it's not meant to create buttons or menus. The best solution is to keep the areas where you want to have a button in some variable and test if the mouse click was inside one of these areas.

Example with a rectangle:

```
if(mouse_x>vertex_x[0] && mouse_x<vertex_x[1] && mouse_y>vertex_y[0] && mouse_y<vertex_y[1])
```

Comment: GL is for drawing, GLUT is for window/context creation and event handling.

Comment: wops, my mistake. But the the solution would be the same